# On add to cart check quantity on grouped products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want on woocommerce to prevent user to add in cart quantity like 2, 3, 4.. The quantity need to be multiply of 7. For example quantity when I'm adding a product need to be 7, 14, 21.. etc.

Bellow is what i've tried

```
function add_the_date_validation() { 
$minimum = 7;
    if (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() % $minimum != 0)
    {
//      wc_clear_notices();
        wc_add_notice(sprintf('You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order.', $minimum), 'error');
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_the_date_validation');
```

But here is checking the total from cart..I want to stop a user to put in cart if the quantity it's not a multiple of 7. And need to be for grouped product type.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 4 );
function woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $valid, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id ) {

    if ( ( $product_id == 22 ) && ($quantity % 7 > 0) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Multiple of 7 required quantity.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        $valid = false;
    }
    return $valid;
}
```

Comment: Won't work:(..i've got an error Missing argument 4 for woocommerce_add_to_cart_validations()

Comment: did you try to copy my code as is? replace your code with mine... it should work

Comment: also change the product id 22 with your product id... or remove `( $product_id == 22 ) &&` if you want all products